# Simple task with algorithms and basic calculations

Tags: logic, algorithms

George, Susan and Sisi are friends. They want to go on a trip to the seaside which is 384 km away from them.
They have a motorcycle that can carry no more than 2 people. The motorcycle moves at a constant speed of 60km/h.
George, Susan and Sisi really want to get to the seaside and can run at a constant speed of 15 km/h. If all three of them leave at the same time, what's the shortest time they can get to the sea?

The answer should be provided in minutes.

I have done:

1. Calculate the time the motorcycle with 2 ppl will reach the sea (6h 24min = 384 min)
2. Calculate what distance the 3rd person went for the above time (384 min & 15km/h = 96KM)
3. Calculate the distance between the 3rd person and the motorcycle on the sea. (384 - 96 = 288KM)
4. Calculate when/where the 3rd person and the motorcycle will meet. (3rd person will travel 57.6KM for 3h 50min and the 230.4KM will be passed for 3h 50min by the motorcycle)
5. The motorcycle will get to the sea for another 3h 50min to the sea.

In the end I ended with 384 + 230 + 230 = 844min, but this seems like incorrect answer...
Where I am wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

You need two intermediate locations (distances from Start). P is distance to Pick-up point for A. (A, B, C are any arrangement of the people.) D is distance to Drop-off point for C. B stays on the bike, first dropping off C, then coming back to pick up A. A runs to P, then rides to F (the distance to Finish (beach).) C rides to D, then runs to F.
Translate each person's travel distance to times, by dividing by velocities (T=D/V):

Ta = (F - D)/15 + D/60

Tb = D/60 + (D - P)/60 + (F - P)/60

Tc = P/15 + (F - P)/60

Ta = Tb = Tc = T, total time.

Solve the system of equations to get
P = F - D = 109.71 km

D - P = 164.58 km

D = F - P = 274.29 km

Evaluate any travel to get T = 713 min.
= 11 h, 53 m